# Error adding articles on the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

Following the example [guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) I receive an error *undefined method `articles' for nil:NilClass* in attempt of addition of article on the page.

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root :to => redirect('/pages/1')
  resources :articles
  resources :pages do
    resources :articles
  end
```

views/articles/new.html.erb

```
<h1>New Article</h1>
<%= form_for([@page, @page.articles.build]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :item %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :item %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

articles_controller.rb

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @page = Page.find(params[:page_id])
    @article = @page.articles.create(article_params)
    redirect_to root_path if @article.save
  end

  private
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:item, :description)
    end
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't defining `@page` in your `new` action.  You need to add something similar to what you've done in `create` to the `new` action (and probably the `edit` action as well).

Comment: Now it is better, but couldn't find Page with 'id'= 
From console log: 
Page Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "pages".* FROM "pages" WHERE "pages"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", nil]]

Answer (score 0):

```
before_action :load_page

...

protected
def load_page
  @page ||= Page.find(params[:page_id])
end
```